# Get the index of selected option in node.js with using express

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I need to get the index of selected object using express to console it in app.js
example.html

```html
<form id="tableForm" action="getJson">
        <select class="example" name="example">
              <option name="table1" value="1">Table 1</option>
              <option name="table2" value="2">Table 2</option>
              <option name="table3" value="3">Table 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

App.js

```html
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/index.html');
});

app.post('/getJson', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body.example);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running at port 3000: http://127.0.0.1:3000')
});
```

this will out put the value of the selected option not the index.

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: I didn’t receive error message but receive the value instead of the index

Comment: @shiva can you please explain why you need to get an index?

Comment: @Staxaaaa I need the index in other project to using it in receiving data from mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for `selected` attribute on `<option>` tag. Also attribute `attribute` is not supported for `<option>` tag.
You cannot get an index from `<select>` tag. You should create a hashtable with indexes and values for this `<select>`. And then when you will get the value get an index for this value from hashtable.
Something like that. Just for example.

```
<form id="tableForm" action="getJson">
    <select class="example" name="example">
          <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
          <option value="Moscow">Moscow</option>
          <option value="Kyiv">Kyiv</option>
    </select>
</form>

const selectHashtable = {
    'Berlin': 1,
    'Moscow': 2,
    'Kyiv': 3
};

// for example req.body.example = 'Kyiv';
// you call 
selectHashtable[req.body.example]; // console.log => 3
```